# Writing and Reading JSON in VB.net using Newtonsoft

Tags: json, vb.net, json.net

This is my first time using JSON and I'm stuck. I'm trying to send a test SMS via http://sms.roamtech.com/smsapi/. The format is:

**Send message format(json).**

```
{
    "result":{
        "account":"xxxx",
        "user":"xxxx",
        "password":"xxxxxxxx",
        "requestType":"BULK",
        "alphanumeric":"xxxxxxxx",
        "data":{
            "linkid":"xxxxxxx",
            "msisdn":"xxxxxxxxxxx",
            "networkid":"1",
            "message":"xxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "callback":"http//test"
        }
    }
}
```

So, this is what I've come up with after reviewing various posts on this and other sites:

```
Imports Newtonsoft.Json
Imports Newtonsoft.Json.Linq
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Text

Module modJSON
     Public Class clsResult
         Public account As String
         Public user As String
         Public password As String
         Public requestType As String
         Public alphanumeric As String
         Public data As New clsData
     End Class
     Public Class clsData
        Public linkid As String
        Public msisdn As String
        Public networkid As String
        Public message As String
        Public callback As String
    End Class
    Public Class clsPOST
        Public result As New clsResult

    End Class

    Public Sub chkJSON()
        Dim r As New clsResult
        Dim d As New clsData
        Dim x As New clsPOST

        r.account = "8852"
        r.user = "username"
        r.password = "password"
        r.requestType = "BULK"
        r.alphanumeric = "SMSLEO"


        d.linkid = "1001"
        d.msisdn = "2547xxxxxxxx"
        d.networkid = "1"
        d.message = "Just a test"
        d.callback = "http://infiniti-africa.com/json"

        r.data = d
        x.result = r

        Dim uriRoam As New Uri("http://sms.roamtech.com/smsapi")
        Dim strJSON = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(x, Formatting.Indented)
        Dim bytJSON = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strJSON)

        Dim result_post = SendRequest(uriRoam, bytJSON, "application/json", "POST")
        MsgBox(result_post)

    End Sub

    Private Function SendRequest(uri As Uri, jsonDataBytes As Byte(), contentType As String, method As String) As String
        Dim req As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create(uri)
        req.ContentType = contentType
        req.Method = method
        req.ContentLength = jsonDataBytes.Length


        Dim stream = req.GetRequestStream()
        stream.Write(jsonDataBytes, 0, jsonDataBytes.Length)
        stream.Close()

        Dim response = req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()

        Dim reader As New StreamReader(response)
        Dim res = reader.ReadToEnd()
        reader.Close()
        response.Close()

        Return res
    End Function
End Module
```

The string `strJSON`seems to contain the correct key:value combinations. However, the code doesn't send the test SMS and I don't get any response. 'SendRequest' returns an empty string.

Also, I'm not sure what to use for the "callback" url, which is where the delivery report is forwarded.

**Note:**
1. `"linkid"` is a unique message ID
2. `"msidn"` is the recipient phone number

Any help is appreciated.

I have also tried using the following class:

```
Public Class JsonPost

    Private urlToPost As String = ""

    Public Sub New(ByVal urlToPost As String)
        Me.urlToPost = urlToPost
    End Sub

    Public Function postData(pstData As Byte()) As Boolean
        Dim webClient As New WebClient()
        Dim resByte As Byte()
        Dim resString As String

        Try
            webClient.Headers("content-type") = "application/json"
            resByte = webClient.UploadData(Me.urlToPost, "post", pstData)
            resString = Encoding.Default.GetString(resByte)
            Console.WriteLine(resString)
            webClient.Dispose()
            Return True
        Catch ex As Exception
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
        End Try
        Return False
    End Function

End Class
```

Then calling:

```
    Dim strJSON = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(x)
    Dim bytJSON = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strJSON)

    Dim jsonPost As New JsonPost("http://sms.roamtech.com/smsapi")
    jsonPost.postData(bytJSON)
```

I'm still getting nothing. Been struggling with this for three days now. Any ideas anyone?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I've been stressing for four days over a trailing slash (/). The API URL is:

> http://sms.roamtech.com/smsapi/

While I've been using:

> http://sms.roamtech.com/smsapi

Lesson learnt.